# Windows Service cannot run a bat file properly on Windows XP - C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, service, windows-xp

I have a windows service, and I want it to automaticly update itself.
So, when my service understands, that there is update, it creates a .bat file:

```
   File.WriteAllLines(updateFileName, new string[] {"sc stop "+ServiceName, 
    "ping 10.10.10.10 -n 8", "DEL "+ServicePath, 
    "RENAME "+NewServicePath+" "+ServicePath, "sc start "+ServiceName})
```

Then I create a process and start it, I have tried both this

```
Process updateProcess = new Process();
updateProcess.StartInfo.FileName = updateFileName;
updateProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
updateProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
updateProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
updateProcess.Start();
```

and this

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/C " + updateFileName,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                Verb = "runas",
                ErrorDialog = false
            };

            updateProcess.StartInfo = psi;
            updateProcess.Start();
```

I have also tried to write a console application updateService.exe that stops, updates and starts service. In this case I've created a .bat file with `ServiceDirectory\updateService.exe` and also tried to run it.

My service using `LocalSystem` account.

All of this things above work perfectly fine on Windows 7.

But on Windows XP it doesn't work:

1. Service stops, ping works, del and rename commands doesn't work,
   service doesn't start again.
2. Service starts .bat file withupdateService.exe, service stops and starts again, but services .exe file doesn't update.

So, I want to know how can I force my service to update itself on Windows XP, I think there is some issues with priveleges, but I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: The obvious debugging technique would be to redirect the output of those commands to file, so you can figure out why they failed. You might need ` 2>` to capture error messages. That said, XP is out of support.

Comment: @MSalters I used output to file, but there was nothin there, files stayed blank.
I know XP is out of support, but our company still uses almost a hundred computers with windows XP and I need this service to work on them

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest to run the created batch file manually from within a command prompt window to see possible problems with command **DEL** and **RENAME** while the service is running.

Second, it was not posted the values of the variables `NewServicePath` and `ServicePath` which might be important here.

I suggest further using instead of

```
DEL ServicePath
RENAME NewServicePath ServicePath
```

the batch code

```
MOVE /Y "Name of new file with full path" "Name of file to update with full path"
```

Using command **MOVE** with parameter `/Y` to overwrite already existing file is much better than using **DEL** and **RENAME** as command **RENAME** requires that second parameter is only the file name without path. And additionally the service file exists after update only once with using **MOVE**.

Using full path for both files is recommended as current directory for batch file execution is not set on creating the process nor inside the batch file.

With using `cd /D "%~dp0"` as first line in batch file it would be possible to set the current directory for the batch file to directory of the batch file.

Comment: 1. created .bat files run perfectly and do everything right, if I start them manually.
2. all of pathes are right (I've checked them after file creation), and rename used as second argument only filename, not full path. I will now try to replace DEL and RENAME with MOVE /Y, thank you

Comment: I've changed DEL and RENAME to MOVE /Y and figuired this: when my Service starts this .bat file commands `sc stop` and `ping` work okay, and then nothing - commands `move /Y` and `sc start` don't execute.
When I start .bat file manually it works fine.
So I think the trouble is in priveleges - but my service start under LocalSystem and starts .bat file with `Verb="runas"`, and I thought this must be sufficient...